# Reloading data locally vs. from the server when going back in activity lifecycle

Tags: android

(There are several similiar questions like [How can I refresh a previous activity after the back button is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175369/how-can-i-refresh-a-previous-activity-after-the-back-button-is-pressed) or [Back button and refreshing previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545217/back-button-and-refreshing-previous-activity), which do not exactly satisfy my needs.)

I'm having two activities:

- **PhotoListActivity**: This activity contains a `RecyclerView` and a `PhotoListAdapter<ArrayList<PhotoModel>>` which displays multiple photos.
- **PhotoDetailActivity**: This activity displays a single photo and it details.

**The problem:** The user starts at the **PhotoListActivity** and ends up in the **PhotoDetailActivity** by clicking a photo. Both activities allow users to like a photo. Liking a photo will result in a request to the server, where the like is saved. When the user now likes a photo in the **PhotoDetailActivity** and presses the back button, the **PhotoListActivity** and its corresponding `PhotoListAdapter<ArrayList<PhotoModel>>` doesn't know anything about this change, because the data of the adapter still contains the "not-liked" photo.

What is the preferred android way to display the updated data?

1. Reload the data for the `PhotoListAdapter<ArrayList<PhotoModel>>` from the server in the `onResume`/`onRestart` method
2. Pass back the updated `PhotoModel` from the **PhotoDetailActivity**, loop through the `PhotoListAdapter<ArrayList<PhotoModel>>`'s ArrayList and update the corresponding `PhotoModel`.
3. Have a local cache (either way static or in SharedPrefs) which holds a list of liked photos. Everytime a user like/unlikes a photo, I could update that cache. Then the only thing I have to do now in my **PhotoListActivity**, is to check if a cache entry for the given photo is set and use the like value for that, instead of the one from the `PhotoModel`. The advantage of that would be, that I don't have to pass around my updated `PhotoModel` all the time.

The second solution is obviously preferable, because we do not have to make another server request, but it seems kind of "hacky" to loop through the `PhotoListAdapter<ArrayList<PhotoModel>>` and update the matching `PhotoModel`.

Is there any better way to solve that in android?

**Edit**: Updated and added a third possible solution.

Comment: You can Use StartActivityForResult and in intent pass your model and update your list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would combine solution number 2 with @[Rajesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43972078/reloading-data-locally-vs-from-the-server-when-going-back-in-activity-lifecycle#comment74974017_43972078) solution. You don't have to loop through the list: If you pass the position index alongside the `PhotoModel`, you will be able to know exactly which position to update in your ArrayList.

**Step 1**

Inside `PhotoListActivity`, Start `PhotoDetailActivity` and pass along the PhotoModel & its position in your ArrayList.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PhotoDetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("photoModel", myPhotoModel);
intent.putExtra("photoModelPosition", position); // = represents the index of array
startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_DETAIL_ACTIVITY); //int const that you choose
```

**Step 2**

Inside `PhotoDetailActivity`, when the user finishes / presses back / whatever your condition is, prepare the updated `PhotoModel` and the position info to be returned to the calling activity:

```
if (photoModelChanged) { //Your condition here..
    int originalPos = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("photoModelPosition");

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("photoModel", updatedPhotoModel);
    intent.putExtra("photoModelPosition", originalPos);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

**Step 3**

Inside `PhotoListActivity`, override `onActivityResult` and implement the updated `PhotoModel` into your existing ArrayList. You can then call your adapter's `notifyItemChanged` if you wish to:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PHOTO_DETAIL_ACTIVITY) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            PhotoModel updatedModel = data.getExtras()
                   .getSerializable("photoModel"); //I assume your class is serializable?
            int pos = data.getExtras().getInt("photoModelPosition");

            //Update the activity's ArrayList<PhotoModel>
            this.arrayList.set(pos, updatedModel);

            //Notify the PhotoListAdapter with the change
            this.adapter.notifyItemChanged(pos);
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing t like this.